# Run An EXE in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I 'execute' an exe from the PowerShell console?

I know in CMD I can enter the name of the exe and it runs, but that isn't working on PowerShell.

In the directory there's an exe called `b2c.exe` that I want to run.

Sample commands I Want to Run:

- b2c get-user
- b2c help
- b2c update-user a80a99a7-b018-423f-90fc-d9a30e5dc7ea ......\usertemplate-update-org-id.json

Working example in cmd prompt, and error message from PowerShell:

[image: error details]

[image: working example in cmd prompt]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think powershell has the current folder in its search path, try:

```
.\b2c
```

Comment: Powershell definitely does not include the current directory in the search path; this is deliberate, as a matter of security.

Answer (score 2):

See [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)

```
& "C:\path\to\b2c.exe" get-user
& "C:\path\to\b2c.exe" help
& "C:\path\to\b2c.exe" update-user a80a99a7-b018-42...
```

Comment: The `&` operator and the quotes are not necessary here since the path/filename of the executable doesn't contain quotes. (It doesn't hurt, but also isn't necessary.)